# Autocrate database ignoring errors if database is down with Spring 5 and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm searching for a very simple way to both initialize a Postgres DB *and* ignore any DB initialization errors using Spring 5 (Spring boot) and Hibernate.

I've been searching for solution for quite a few hours now but nothing working. Using property `spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true` works correctly and prevent application from crashing when on connection refused exceptions. But it doesn't prevent application from crashing when used in combination with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

I've tried a few  things like programmatically initialize the DB but I can't find an easy solution as I don't have much time to spend on this. All of this is just for demonstrating some technlogy for students. So I really don't care if the Postgres database is present or not. I just want both database autocreation and population *and* no crash if Postgres is down.

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question sounds strange. Usually database is a critical resource for application. Please describe what role database play in your app and how you see the work of app without database.

Comment: This us just a demo app for a Docker lesson for students. So it basically does nothing except saying *Hello* on `/` and display a few data from DB on `/tasks`/. But in a first practice I just make them play with only one Docker container. Then, with a second. It's just I wanted them to play with the same project from beginnning to end. So I wanted the project to work even when the DB is not there yet. And it's also a way for me to learn a bit more about Spring.

Comment: I'm just surprised not to find the answer anywhere. It looked like a legitimate question to have the DB automatically setup when it exists but also a fallback if it does not exist.